# index 243 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

Tags: python, numpy, keras, data-science, linear-algebra

I am getting an error "index 243 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10" and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Also, I was wondering if there is a general guideline for linear algebra and keras.

Let me know what y'all think!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D

img_rows, img_cols = 16, 16
num_classes = 10

image_file = "../input/pic-test/output2.csv"
image_data = np.loadtxt(image_file,skiprows=1, delimiter=',') #skiprows=1,

def prep_data(raw):
    y = raw[:, 0]
    out_y = keras.utils.to_categorical(y,num_classes) #num_classes

    x = raw[:,1:]
    num_images = raw.shape[0]
    out_x = x.reshape(num_images, img_rows, img_cols,1)
    out_x = out_x / 255
    return out_x, out_y

x, y = prep_data(image_data)

image_model = Sequential()

image_model.add(Conv2D(12,
                         activation='relu',
                         kernel_size=3,
                         input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)))

image_model.add(Conv2D(20, activation='relu', kernel_size=3))
image_model.add(Conv2D(20, activation='relu', kernel_size=3))
image_model.add(Flatten())
image_model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
image_model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

image_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

image_model.fit(x, y, batch_size=100, epochs=4, validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: I have no idea where that error is occurring.  And no idea of the shape of the arrays.   When working with `numpy` arrays (and Python lists) you need a clear idea of what shapes you expect, and shapes you actually get.  NO GUESSING.

Comment: Here's a gues.  `num_classes` is 10.  ``y/raw` comes form `image_data`.  `243` is a reasonable image pixel value.  Is the `to_categorical` trying map pixel values on to categories?  Is there were the error occurs?

Comment: What does `y.shape` tell you? It has to be `(?, 10)` in order to work properly.